# Elixir only compiles to app.css

Tags: laravel, sass, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm using Laravel5 elixir to generate css files from my .scss files

this is my gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix
        .sass(['homepage.scss'])
});
```

for some reason the output is always app.css instead of homepage.css
any ideas? I updated elixir to "laravel-elixir": "^3.0.0"

what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading documentation I saw that for "styles" we can have three arguments, one is an array that specifies the style files, second argument is the output file name and third argument is a resulting directory.

Reading [sass task source code](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/master/tasks/sass.js) we see that first argument is an array of files and the second argument is the output file.

Adding a second argument to your code we have:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix
        .sass(['homepage.scss'], 'homepage.css')
});
```